# Operators with eigenvalue $\{0,1\}$ that is not projection

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Show that there are linear operators T on the Hilbert space H what are not orthogonal projections, but their spectrum consists of the eigenvalues $\{0,1\}.$

I can not come up with an counterexample, but I suppose it must be infinite dimension?
Hilbert spaces has orthogonal bases and I did an exersice showing that for projections $T'(T-I) = 0$ So obviously $T \neq TT'$, is zero some kind of accumulation point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 57 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Oh it was this easy! thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To complement Nate Eldredge's example, it might be more interesting to consider operators that are projections, but not *orthogonal* projections. We can rephrase this in terms of the SVD: An orthogonal projection is an operator $T$ such that $T^2 = T$, and such that the singular values of $T$ are each either $0$ or $1$.

A non-orthogonal projection, also called an *oblique* projection, is one for which $T^2 = T$, but the singular values of $T$ may not belong to $\{0,1\}$. Consider this example:
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
We can check that $A^2 = A$, so this is a projection, but it is not an orthogonal projection, since
$$ A^* A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$